# Regex to match suffixes to english words

Tags: regex, perl

I'm searching for the word "move" and i want to match "moved" as well when I print.

The way I'm going about this is:

```
if ($sentence =~ /($search_key)d$/i) {
   $search_key = $search_keyd;
}
$subsentences[$i] =~ s/$search_key/ **$search_key** /i;                         
$subsentences[$i] =~ s/\b$parsewords[1]_\w+/ --$parsewords[1]--/i;                          
print "MATCH #$count\n",split(/_\S+/,$subsentences[$i]), "\n";
$count++;
```

This is part of a longer code so if anything is unclear let me know. The _ is because the words in the sentence are tagged (ex. I_NN move_VB to_PREP ....).

Where `$search_keyd` will be  `$search_key."d"`, which worked!

A nice addition would be to check if the word ended in e and therefore only a d would need to be appended. I'd guess it'd look something like this: `e?$/d$`

Even a general answer will suffice.

I'm new to Perl. So sorry if this is elementary. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The title doesn't quite match what you are asking.  You may want to rephrase it for clarity.

Comment: Do you want to match "moving" too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to search for `"move"` and add a highlight, but also include any variation of the basic word, such as `"moves" "moved"`.

When you are replacing words in a text like this, you usually want to replace **all** the words, and then you need the `/g` operator on the regex, like so:

```
$subsentences[$i] =~ s/$search_key/ **$search_key** /ig
```

Also, you should make sure to not match partials of words. E.g. you want to match `"move"`, but not perhaps `"remove"`. For this, you can use `\b` to mark word boundry:

```
$subsentences[$i] =~ s/\b$search_key/ **$search_key** /ig
```

In order to match certain suffixes, you need a character class with valid characters or combination of characters. `move[sd]` will find `"moves"` and `"moved"`. However, for a word like `"jump"`, you would need to be a bit more specific: `"jump(s|ed)"`. Note that `[sd]` can be replaced with `(s|d)`. So barring any bad spelling in your text, you can get away with:

```
$subsentences[$i] =~ s/\b$search_key(s|d|ed)/ **$search_key$1** /ig
```

Note that `$1` matches whatever is found inside the first matching parenthesis.

To find the number of matching words:

```
my $matches = $subsentences[$i] =~ s/\b$search_key(s|d|ed)/ **$search_key$1** /ig
```

If you want to be more specific with the suffixes, i.e. make it not match badly spelled words like `"moveed"`, you'd need to do some special matching. Something like:

```
if ($search_key =~ /e$/i) { $suffix = '(s|d)' }
else { $suffix = '(s|ed)' }
my $matches = $subsentences[$i] =~ s/\b$search_key$suffix/ **$search_key$1** /ig
```

It can probably become very complicated the more search words you add.

Some help about regexes [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the step-by-step! I just changed   
    if ($subsentences[$i] =~ /e$/i) { $suffix = '(s|d)' } 
to
   if ($search_key[$i] =~ /e$/i) { $suffix = '(s|d)' }
and then separated s and d cases because they corresponded to different cases. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, yes of course. You want to check the search pattern, not the text. =) My bad. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to match all complete words which begin with your search term, i.e. 'move' matches 'move', 'moved', 'movers', etc, then you want to use a character class to detect the end of the word.

So, instead of:

```
if ($sentence =~ /($search_key)d$/i)
```

Try using:

```
if ($sentence =~ /($search_key\w*)\W$/i)
```

The \w* will match any number of standard word characters and the \W should prevent you from including other characters, such as whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: Ya I had that, except for the print statement, it must print that word as well, which didn't really work... also I don't want movers or movement etc... it still needs to be move as a verb, so moves and moved are good for now... move[s e*d] maybe?

Comment: @Jon: You cannot use * in a character class that way, but even if you could that would match move and moves but it would also match moveee which I doubt you want.

Comment: @Jon: Why such a specific matching scheme?  What are you trying to do with this?